# Google pay merchant is not enabled for direct tokenization

Tags: android, google-pay

I am working on google pay integration.I tried with google pay test environment, added real card it is giving response but it has no token. Actually we are trying direct tokenization with production environment, My company provided public key and i added in google pay console it is showing inactive. Still i added public key and protocol version in android app but it is showing merchant is not enabled.

1. Is it possible to get encrypted token in google pay test environment ?
2. What is the process to get merchant Id for google pay.

code:

```
[![val DIRECT_TOKENIZATION_PARAMETERS = mapOf(
            "protocolVersion" to "ECv1",
            "publicKey" to DIRECT_TOKENIZATION_PUBLIC_KEY
    )

 private fun directTokenizationSpecification(): JSONObject {

        return JSONObject().apply {
            put("type", "DIRECT")
            put("parameters", JSONObject(Constants.DIRECT_TOKENIZATION_PARAMETERS))
        }
    }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get encrypted token in google pay test environment?

It should be possible get an encrypted token in the test environment, however, the token won't represent a real card, instead, you'll get a *dummy* card.

> What is the process to get merchant Id for google pay?

You can get a merchant id from the [Google Pay Business Console](https://pay.google.com/business/console). If you've signed in and registered, the merchant id will be visible in the top right hand corner.

> My company provided public key and i added in google pay console it is showing inactive. Still i added public key and protocol version in android app but it is showing merchant is not enabled.

This will need to be activated by the Google Pay team before this can be used. Note that the preferred type of integration is via one of the [supported payment service providers](https://developers.google.com/pay/api#participating-processors). DIRECT integration is considerably more onerous as it requires you to regularly rotate your encryption keys and provide evidence of PCI compliance.

Comment: Thanks @Soc, i tried with sample android gpay code with my real card, i got response but i can't see token. Do i need to do anything extra to get encrypted token in test environment